# ssh-agent/ssh-add - how can I force confirmation by default?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I use ssh forwarding alot and I'm concerned about "agent hijacking", so, I like to use `-c` option when calling `ssh-add`, which enforces confirmation on every key usage.

**How can I turn the confirmations on by-default**, so I don't have to use `-c` every time?

***inb4*** "Use bash aliases, Luke!": aliases are good thing, but I look for more convinient way to enforce this `ssh-add` behavior. If there just isn't any, aliases will be enough.

Comment: After reading the manual page of `ssh-add` you will notice that there is no setting which would allow you to do this by default. Ergo the answer is either to use aliases or `mv` ssh-add to some other location, then call it from a script named `ssh-add`. But you knew that already.

Comment: @SamiLaine yes, I've read man page for ssh-add and ssh several times and found no such way - so, I've decided, that I may miss something. So, I've asked this question.
If there isn't any, I think, this is a good feature to request. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On macOS Mojave I have the following in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent confirm
```

From the man page:

> Specifies whether keys should be automatically added to a running
> ssh-agent(1).

> If this option is set to "confirm", each use of the
> key must be confirmed, as if the -c option was specified to
> ssh-add(1).

So I use plain `ssh`. The first time I do connect to a server it asks for a password. On subsequent connections it asks for a confirmation (I had to install [ssh-askpass](https://github.com/theseal/ssh-askpass)).

Comment: Thank you. I can try to confirm this tomorrow and accept the answer then.

Comment: Confirmed that it works, marked as an accepted answer. Thanks.